# format date in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I was trying to learn how to format date in oracle pl oracle, when I ran below query its returns error

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'YYYY-DD-MM') FROM dual;

the error message is

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Comment: With `TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'YYYY-DD-MM')` you are telling the DBMS "I have a string that starts with a four-digit year, then a dash, then a two digit day, then a dash, then a two-digit month. Please convert this into a date.". But you are giving the DBMS the string `'01-JAN-00'`, which does not start with a four-digit year etc. Oracle tells you that the given format and string don't match.

Comment: On a side note: you should avoid two-digit years (like `'00'` in your example). Use four-digits years wherever possible. Think about it; what would `'01-JAN-99'` be? 1999 or 2099 and why?

Comment: ... Well, dates in strings should be avoided anyway. Sometimes, however, this is not possible, e.g. when writing into a file or reading from one. `TO_DATE` is very rarely needed. Its counterpart `TO_CHAR` is more likely to be used, but again, why would you create a date string in SQL? Shouldn't the app calling the database know better how its user wants dates displayed? Again it's when writing into files, when we might use the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for my scenario I had to use to_char which perfectly solve the formatting issue.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('01-JAN-00', 'yyyy-DD-MM') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are either not using the correct format specifier, or not passing the correct string. You want:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM') FROM DUAL;
```

Or:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL;
```

Or you can simply declare a `DATE` litteral:

```
SELECT DATE'2000-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: @Afeez Olawale: Use `TO_DATE` only when you are getting a string from somewhere that contains a date. (That should be a rare situation. Usually you would already have dates, not strings, when dealing with dates.) Use a date literal when you know the date. Here is the docs on literals in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ

Comment: this doesn't for my use case, I have been able to resolve this using TO_CHAR